# Using conditions in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am working with some XML files where in some instances the *HName* node is available in some files while missing from the others. Here are two examples:

**Xml #1:**

```
<HSegment>
<Code>ABC</Code> 
</HSegment>
```

**Xml #2:**

```
<HSegment>
<Code>ABC</Code> 
<HName>JW BEACH</HName>  
</HSegment>
```

I am trying to parse the xml files using two conditions:

1. Process the value within the  data field if it's available.
2. Otherwise inserting ‘NULL’ if it's not available.

The XSL code that i am working with below adds ‘NULL’ to both cases:

```
<Des>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//PNR/SList/HSegment/HName='HName'">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text> 
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</Des>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the presence check to look like this:

```
//PNR/SList/HSegment/HName
```

In context:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//PNR/SList/HSegment/HName">
        <!-- do whatever -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I tried that approach as well. This doesn't parse the XML files which have the (HName) node in them. They fail altogether.

Comment: I have tested and this works fine. If it's failing, then it's for some other reason you haven't mentioned in your question.